# Grid/Matrix in Content Elements

Tags: grid, content, blocks

I doubt I'm the first person to request this, but it seems such an obvious requirement I can't believe it's not been done as yet.  I'm looking at [Content Elements](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements), or [Blocks](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/blocks) I want to be able to place a grid (or matrix) within either of these systems, but I can't seem to find a solution that allows this?  Is it simply impossible or has no one else had the requirement? seems kind of an obvious requirement and would mean that these block builders offer the full flexibility that I need.

Please note blocks allows Nolan to be used inside it, however this isn't as flexible or user-friendly as I require.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You may find yourself hard up here, as from my first glance neither of these modules support native field types, instead supplying their own.

Personally I develop blocks and block embedding systems by hand depending on the client requirement, then to populate these blocks I might use [Low:Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) (which does support Grid, Matrix, P&T fields, anything!) to define the variables for that block.

If its a template and you may have many blocks of the type, why not drive the blocks off a channel field?

Just some ideas for you as you haven't had an answer yet...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've just had a quick play with low variables, looks great, but doesn't quite offer the flexibility that I need/wanted, I'd come to the conclusion that channels for the various content types with playa to set and order those blocks was going to be the best solution, but it's a bit abstract for my client so I'd wanted to avoid it if possible. looks like I'm wanting something beyond EE. :(

Comment: Have you approched the writers of Content Elements or Blocks with a feature request? Grid is a native ee field so you could ask them if they are looking to add support inthe near future, as these modules are premiium paid for you should get a decent response from their support.

Comment: I did indeed contact both Content Elements and Blocks to see if they would/do support grid or matrix, blocks said I could use nolan, which I tried and wasn't an ideal solution, Content Elements said that their very busy at the moment and wouldn't be looking at it any time soon :) fun fun fun